# Displaying image by clicking the spinner

Tags: java, android, spinner, android-spinner

I want to click the spinner and next page to display an image from the drawable in android studio.

This shows the spinner only

```
public class navigation extends AppCompatActivity implements AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_navigation);

    Spinner end = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.end_spinner);
    //Create an ArrayAdapter using the string array and a default spinner layout
    ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> end_adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this, R.array.end_point, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
    //Specify the layout to use when the list of choices appears
    end_adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    //Apply the adapter to the spinner
    end.setAdapter(end_adapter);
    end.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
}

@Override
public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
    if (parent.getId() == R.id.end_spinner){
        if(position >=1 && position <=16){
            TextView mytext = (TextView) view;
            Toast.makeText(this,mytext.getText()+" selected",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            Intent PlanIntent = new Intent(navigation.this, AStar.class);
            Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
            bundle.putInt("classname",position);
            PlanIntent.putExtras(bundle);
            startActivity(PlanIntent);
        }
        else {
            Toast.makeText(this,"Please select the destination",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }
}

        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent)
        {
            Spinner start = (Spinner) findViewById(end_spinner);
            assert start != null;
            start.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
            if (start.getId() != end_spinner) {

            }

        }
@Override
public void onBackPressed(){
    startActivity(new Intent(this,MainActivity.class));
    finish();
}
}
```

This is the next page that can show the image

public class AStar extends AppCompatActivity {

```
ImageView imageView;

PhotoViewAttacher mAttacher;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_astar);

    imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);
    int position = getIntent().getIntExtra("classname", -1);
    if(position != -1){
        int classImg = classImages[position];
        imageView.setImageResource(classImg);
    }

    mAttacher = new PhotoViewAttacher(imageView);
}
}
```

I have 16 class names in the spinner, what I want to do is that when the user clicks the each class name it will show a picture from drawable. each class name has a different image. My idea is use if else but I don't know the code.

Answer (score 1):

You already know how to use `R.array.end_point`, so make another xml array of the same size for the corresponding drawables.

You also  know how to use `bundle.putInt("classname",position);`, so you now need to get that integer in the second Activity from the intent.

With those two concepts, you can then get the drawable at a specific position in the second Activity, and draw the image accordingly

```
imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);
int position = getIntent().getIntExtra("classname", -1);
if(position != -1){
    // TODO: get some R.array.classImages
    int classImg = classImages[position];
    imageView.setImageResource(classImg);
}
```

> My idea is use if else

That's the wrong idea. See above. No else statements and only one if statement to make sure you've gotten the intent extras. All you need is an array of integers for the drawable resources

Comment: Ya.     if(bundle != null){

        } here i don't know how to write the if else code only

Comment: You don't any  else statements... Not sure why you think you do

Comment: Start with `int classPosition = bundle.getInt`

Comment: Because i have 16 classname in the spinner, then each classname have own image show in next page

Comment: Right.... As I said, no else statements are necessary. You get the position of the clicked item... You lookup the position in a separate array of images

Comment: Wow...but i not so understand...classImages is the image name?my 16 images also different name.

Comment: The name of the image doesn't matter. All you're doing is loading a resource file

Comment: I follow the code but classImages have red line. My drawable also have other image such as button image, logo and so on.

Comment: Right... It obviously will have a red line if you didn't implement the TODO comment to get said array value... That's up to you to code

Comment: Mean i cannot put the TODO comment? I delete the comment also same have red line

Comment: You need to **create** your own `int[]` array named `classImages`. That's what `TODO` means here. Please try to understand the code rather than simply copy and paste it. That's not any way to learn

Comment: Thank a lot you teaching me, i finally done it, but have bug when i click it, it can show image, but when i press back then select again it will crush.